# Are both "How did you" and "Howdja" used?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, ipa

How did you get here? [ 'haʊ dɪdʒʊ 'gɛt hɪər? ]
I took the bus.

How did you get here? [ 'haʊdʒə 'gɛt hɪər? ]
I took the train.

My question: are both "haʊ dɪdʒʊ" and "haʊdʒə" used in American English? I think that "haʊdʒə" is more informal, but I think both mean the same thing. Am I right?

Comment: You are right, and both are used.

Comment: "How did you" can easily morph into "how didja" or "howdja" when spoken rapidly and without taking care to enunciate.  The meaning doesn't change, except perhaps to imply a reduced level of formality (which might cause the other party to respond with different details, eg).

Comment: I would think "howdja" would be the spoken approximation of the contraction *How'd you*, whereas "how didja" would correspond to *How did you*. But they do mean the same thing.

Comment: Here's how Woody Guthrie pronounces "[Howdi Do](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_DYJK9pCwPE)," multiple times.

Comment: They are exactly the same, and it's not a matter of formality. They are context-driven "stress timed" utterances.